# SQL Server Management Studio Import Data from Oracle BadImageFormatException

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, ssms

While trying to use SQL Server Management Studio Import and Export Wizard to import data from an Oracle 11g database into my SQL Server database, I encountered an error at the point of testing my connection to the configured Oracle Data Source. I selected ".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle" as "Data Source" on the wizard.

Below is a paste of the error log followed by a screenshot:

> The operation could not be completed.
>
> Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed. (System.Data.OracleClient)

[image]

I have Oracle Instant Client 18.3, 64-bit version installed on my computer and I've included the path of the Instant Client in my `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this error is due to a problem that SQL Server Management Studio has with the 64-bit version of Oracle client. Hence, the fix was to install the 32-bit version of the Oracle Client and point to that installation

Here are the exact steps I followed to resolve the error:

1. I installed Oracle Instant Client 12.2 (which is currently the latest 32-bit version of the Oracle Instant Client) to my computer
2. I then added the installation path of this 32-bit client to my PATH environment variable.
3. I restarted SQL Server Management Studio

Once I did this and re-opened the Import and Export Wizard, I was able to connect seamlessly to my Oracle database and I went on to complete the migration of data from tables in the Oracle database to tables in my SQL Server database.

The connection string I used is in the format below:

```
Data Source=$ORACLE_DB_HOST:$PORT/$SERVICE_NAME;User Id=$USERNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server 2016 Import and Export Data (64-bit) available at "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2016", this works perfectly with Oracle Client 64 bit.